# Not able to connect ssh(port 22) for aws ubuntu 16.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have AWS ec2 instance. 
OS: ubuntu 16.04

SSH was working fine previously. But after enabling ssl module, ssh stopped connecting.

Port 22 is enabled from inbound rule. But still, cant connect ssh or ftp. (So not able to connect with code or db also)

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Is the inbound rule set to allow connection from any IP addresses on port 22?

Comment: Yes. inbound rule is set to allow connection from anywhere for port 22.

Comment: which ssl module have you enabled?

Comment: mod_ssl i have enabled for apache2. May be port 22 was disabled from ufw while installing ssl.